# Tooltips like Twitter for Mac or Sparrow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, tooltip

I am trying to create custom tooltips like the ones found in Twitter for Mac, or even Sparrow. Do you have any direction for achieving this?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards,

Comment: What are you exactly looking for? Maybe you can add a screenshot? I don't have Sparrow or Twitter for Mac :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for MAAttachedWindow?

http://mattgemmell.com/source

Answer (score -1):

Those tooltips are provided by [Growl](http://growl.info/)

Comment: I am talking about teh tooltips, not the notifications.